# How to develop tool in C/C++ whose command interface is Tcl shell?

Tags: tcl

Suppose a tool X need to developed which are written in C/C++ and having Tcl commanline interface, what will the steps or way?

I know about Tcl C API which can be used to extend Tcl by writing C extension for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're looking to do is *embedding Tcl* (totally a supported use case; Tcl remembers that it is a C library) but still making something tclsh-like. The simplest way of doing this is:

Grab a copy of `tclAppInit.c` (e.g., [this](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcl/artifact/df39ad81dccb803f) is the current one in the Tcl 8.6 source tree as I write this) and adapt it, probably by putting the code to register your extra commands, linked variables, etc. in the `Tcl_AppInit()` function; you can probably trim a bunch of stuff out simply enough. Then build and link directly against the Tcl library (*without* stubs) to get effectively your own custom tclsh with your extra functionality.

You can use Tcl's API more extensively than that if you're not interested in interactive use. The core for non-interactive use is:

```
// IMPORTANT: Initialises the Tcl library internals!
Tcl_FindExecutable(argv[0]);

Tcl_Interp *interp = Tcl_CreateInterp();
// Register your custom stuff here

int code = Tcl_Eval(interp, "your script");
// Or Tcl_EvalFile(interp, "yourScriptFile.tcl");

const char *result = Tcl_GetStringResult(interp);
if (code == TCL_ERROR) {
    // Really good idea to print out error messages
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: %s\n", result);
    // Probably a good idea to print error traces too; easier from in Tcl
    Tcl_Eval(interp, "puts stderr $errorInfo");
    exit(1);
}

// Print a non-empty result
if (result[0]) {
    printf("%s\n", result);
}
```

That's about all you need unless you're doing interactive use, and that's when `Tcl_Main()` becomes really useful (it handles quite a few extra fiddly details), which the sample `tclAppInit.c` (mentioned above) shows how to use.

Answer (score 4):

Usually, SWIG (Simplified Wrapper and Interface Generator) is the way to go.
[SWIG HOMEPAGE](http://www.swig.org/)

This way, you can write code in C/C++ and define which interface you want to expose.

suppose you have some C functions you want added to Tcl:

```
/* File : example.c */

 #include <time.h>
 double My_variable = 3.0;

 int fact(int n) {
     if (n <= 1) return 1;
     else return n*fact(n-1);
 }

 int my_mod(int x, int y) {
     return (x%y);
 }

 char *get_time()
 {
     time_t ltime;
     time(&ltime);
     return ctime(&ltime);
 }
```

Now, in order to add these files to your favorite language, you need to write an "interface file" which is the input to SWIG. An interface file for these C functions might look like this :

```
 /* example.i */
 %module example
 %{
 /* Put header files here or function declarations like below */
 extern double My_variable;
 extern int fact(int n);
 extern int my_mod(int x, int y);
 extern char *get_time();
 %}

 extern double My_variable;
 extern int fact(int n);
 extern int my_mod(int x, int y);
 extern char *get_time();
```

At the UNIX prompt, type the following:

```
 unix % swig -tcl example.i
 unix % gcc -fpic -c example.c example_wrap.c \
        -I/usr/local/include 
 unix % gcc -shared example.o example_wrap.o -o example.so
 unix % tclsh
 % load ./example.so example
 % puts $My_variable
 3.0
 % fact 5
 120
 % my_mod 7 3
 1
 % get_time
 Sun Feb 11 23:01:07 2018
```

The swig command produces a file example_wrap.c that should be compiled and linked with the rest of the program. In this case, we have built a dynamically loadable extension that can be loaded into the Tcl interpreter using the 'load' command.

Taken from http://www.swig.org/tutorial.html

Comment: This is indeed the way to go (regardless of weather you end up using SWIG). Extending Tcl is much cleaner than embedding Tcl

Comment: The command you made is example of extending Tcl. But what I want is to develop a tool X which provide some commands foo1 foo2 and so on. Now to use these functions, I will invoke tool. Now after invoking tool, to access its functions, either GUI or command line interface will be needed. I want Tcl as command line interface so I can type and use this functions and post process its output.

Comment: @Drektz, I simplified it as much as possible, there are no limits to what can be achieved with SWIG, including QT GUI or complex C++ applications. I suggest you dig into it further. However, know that SWIG gets quite complicated with time.